# Ayuda en modelo relacional para un sistema de Time Tracking

Tags: mysql, relaciones, lógica, modelorelacional, tablas

Procedo a explicar de que se trata el proyecto que acabo de empezar para poder explicar mi inquietud.

Se trata de un sistema de time tracking pero en su nivel mas básico, nada comparado con los grandes sistemas que ya existe ( primaERP, Harvest etc ) en el que el cliente quiere que funcione de la siguiente manera:

1-Que en el sistema existan 3 tipos de usuarios, los niveles serian(admin,empleado,cliente). Por supuesto cada usuario tendrá acceso al sistema y tendrá permisos propios depende del tipo de usuario que sea.

2-El admin tendrá todos los privilegios del sistema, los cuales describiré los mas importantes:

Creación de empleados y creación de clientes, los cuales tendrán acceso al sistema a través del correo electrónico y una clave establecida.

Asignación de tareas a empleados, en esta parte el admin le asignara a un empleado una tarea en especifico y un cliente especifico, ademas debe ingresar el tiempo de duración de la tarea que puede siempre sera de 2 semanas por tarea y con la peculiaridad de que son 100 horas máximo por tarea.

**Aquí surge mi primera duda, la cual es de que forma guardar esos dos últimos datos (cant semanas y horas máximas), lo que pienso es guardar en seco asi los dos datos, 2 y 100(si se puede hacer mejor, agradecería mucho la ayuda)**

Teniendo la tarea asignada ya a un empleado, el usuario ingresara al sistema y vera que tareas tiene asignadas para comenzar con su time tracking semanal que funcionara de la siguiente manera:

El empleado entra a la tarea que tiene asignada para empezar su día de trabajo, ingresado un hora de entrada, luego hora de almuerzo, hora de vuelta al trabajo y la hora de salida del trabajo. Al tener las 4 horas el sistema calculara las horas totales de trabajo del día y el empleado procederá a aprobar su día de trabajo perteneciente a la tarea que le fue asignada y correspondiente a la semana 1.

**Aquí tengo la otra duda, de que forma puedo guardar el tracking del día, pensé en guardar una fila por cada día con sus respectivas 4 horas, pero como haría para saber a que numero de semana pertenecen esos días de trabajo, si es a la 1 o a la 2**

Al terminar la semana, el empleado aprobara su time tracking semanal, para que posteriormente el cliente ingrese al sistema y proceda a aprobarle la semana al empleado.

**Aquí esta la otra duda, pienso manejar esto de aprobar los días y semanas con un campo tipo bool, pero mi duda esta en que si yo apruebo mi primera semana, como hago para cuando me toque aprobar la segunda**

En si, esta ultima duda va mas por el lado en que no se me ocurre la forma como saber que días pertenecen a tal semana, si es a la 1 o a la 2.

Mostrare el modelo relacional que llevo hasta ahora, agradezco mucho ayuda para poder plantearlo bien, porque no tengo muchas cosas claras.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resumiendo mis dudas son:

1-De que manera guardar los datos de horas máximas y numero de semanas.

Ya que por ejemplo con el campo horas máximas, debo ya sea ir restandole diario a 100 horas cada vez que el empleado apruebe un día. O de irle sumando a ese campo cada vez que el empleado apruebe un día. Y el campo de numero de semanas no se si guardarlo en seco del que llegue por POST, mi duda en este dato esta en que no se de que manera pueda usarlo para llevar el control de los días, para saber a que semana le pertenecen tales días.

2-La 2da duda es cual seria la mejor forma de guardar el tracking semanal, si ir guardando día por día que creo que es la forma en que se deba hacer o habrá otra mejor manera.

3-Y la ultima es cual es la mejor forma de manejar los datos de aprobación, tanto de días como de semanas. Pienso en campos bool, no tengo tantas dudas para la aprobación del día, pero si al momento de aprobar la semana, porque como dije serán 2 semanas de trabajo, entonces de que manera puedo saber cuando apruebo la semana 1 y la semana 2.

Le he dado muchas vueltas al asunto, pero me esta fallando la lógica para armar las tablas. Y el problema principal creo que esta en lo de las semanas, como saber a que semana pertenecen los 5 días del time tracking de cada usuario.

Me seria de mucha ayuda vuestra orientación y consejos para poder armar bien el modelo relacional. Gracias.